# VBA Excel - Rectangular grid of data into column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to reorder a rectangular grid of data into a column.  I have written some code and run some MsgBox's to test some things and it seems to work right, except for the last line.  That is, I have tested to make sure outputArray actually ends up with data in it and various other things.  But, when I try to write the data in outputArray to the worksheet, it just enters all blanks (I had a previous version which didn't automatically delete the original data, so I could see just the first column being blanked out).  I assume it's some easy mistake I can't see.  Can you help me figure out what's wrong?  (Excel 2010)

```
Sub PutDataIntoColumn()
' This sub assumes data comes in a rectangular grid
' And that data is read across row 1, then across row 2, and so on
' The data is reordered into a column of data and is output starting at the top left cell of the original rectangular grid
' The original grid of data is erased so only the column remains

    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim inputArray() As Variant, outputArray() As Variant

    Set inputRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select Data", Title:="Data Into Column", Type:=8)
    inputArray = inputRange.Value

    ' Erase the data
    inputRange.Value = ""

    numRows = UBound(inputArray, 1)
    numCols = UBound(inputArray, 2)

    totalCells = numRows * numCols

    ReDim outputArray(totalCells, 1)

    firstCellRow = inputRange.Row
    firstCellCol = inputRange.Column

    For i = 1 To numRows
        For j = 1 To numCols
            outputArray((i - 1) * numCols + j, 1) = inputArray(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Cells(firstCellRow, firstCellCol).Resize(totalCells).Value = outputArray

End Sub
```

Comment: You may need to transpose the array before writing it to the sheet.  `...= Application.Transpose(outputArray)`

Comment: @Tim, not so, the `For` loops iterate the range just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy mistake you are looking for is the lack of explicit lower bounds on your `outputArray`.  Change the `ReDim` to

```
ReDim outputArray(1 To totalCells, 1 To 1)
```

Without this `outputArray` is declared 0 based, so is one row and column bigger than you expected

FYI, an alternative to `inputRange.Value = ""` is `inputRange.Clear`